# Are .htaccess directives applied downward to subfolders and subfolders with those folders?

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, multisite

I have the .htaccess file detailed below which contains certain directives for HTTP_REFERER, HTTP_USER_AGENT, and WordPress.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} acertainwebsite\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} acertainwebsite.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) wordpress/$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ wordpress/$2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I'm running on a VPS with FreeBSD.  I'm not sure how to test if the directives RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} and RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} in the root .htaccess file are being enforced in lower level subdirectories.

The latest version of Wordpress 4.1.1. is installed with the multisite option on/enabled using the subdirectories structure option.

I suspect that some referrer traffic may be getting past the .htaccess file at the root directory.  I read somewhere that the directives in the .htaccess file cascade upwards, that Apache looks first in the subdirectory, then in the parent, then in the parent to the parent.

So here is the question.  Am I going to have to put .htaccess files in each of the subdirectories of the multisite installation?  Or am I ok with a single .htaccess file in the root directory of the multisite installation?

If I have to have an .htaccess file in each of the multi-site domain subdirectories, would be it sufficient to put an empty .htaccess file in the subdomain?  Would that trigger the upward cascading to check for enforcement?

If you have a good explanation of how this might work, or a reference to another source that explains it better, let me know.  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

There way htaccess files work between parent and subdirectories really depends on the directives. Some directives use the parent htaccess directive and apply only stricter subsets of those directives in subdirectories (like directives involving permissions) and some directives, the subdirectories take complete precedence over anything in a parent htaccess (like with mod_rewrite).

The thing about mod_rewrite is, if there are rules in a subdirectory's htaccess file, *only those rules will be executed*. Any rules in the parent's htaccess file will be completely ignored, unless the subdirectory includes some variation of `RewriteOptions Inherit` to include the parent htaccess rules. In Apache 2.2, inheriting rules only means the parent rules get appended *to the end* of the rules in a subdirectory, while 2.4 allows for more specific appending/prepending of parent rules.

If you have an application in a subdirectory, like wordpress, then those rules will take affect while any rules in your parent directory will be completely ignored (like your referer rules). What you'll need to do is copy those rules into subdirectory htaccess files (and in this case, place them *above* any of the rules that are already there) if you want them to get applied.

If you have subfolders with htaccess files (or not) without any rewrite rules, then the rules in the parent directory will take effect.